# What is LPErrorDomain error 2?

Tags: ipados, shortcuts-app

I was sent a Shortcut to pull URLs from a file and paste them into a bookmark manager app on my iPad. When I run the Shortcut I get this error message. (Attaching a screenshot of the Shortcut)[image]

Comment: Try placing a Quicklook before the repeat to see what you are collecting from the file. I have a feeling it's the information that's coming in that isn't correct.

Answer (score 0):

[LPErrorDomain](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/linkpresentation/lperrordomain) is the domain for Link Presentation errors.

It means that the link you provided cannot be displayed correctly.

Error 2 is a [LPError.Code.metadataFetchFailed](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/linkpresentation/lperror/code/metadatafetchfailed):

> An error indicating that a metadata fetch failed.

Without having the link itself, it's diffcult to know why this error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

The error is due to a malformed URL. But, also, in the loop the “Add Bookmark for..” should be Repeat Item as the variable, not URLs.